# C# How to condense this code into a more efficient manner

Tags: c#

I'm trying to ping multiple sites (Check if they're online), I'm using this code to ping them,

```
        private bool Ping(string url)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
            request.Timeout = 3000;
            request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
            request.Method = "HEAD";

            using (var response = request.GetResponse())
            {
                lblMiamiStatus.Text = "Online";
                lblMiamiStatus.ForeColor = Color.LimeGreen;
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            lblMiamiStatus.Text = "Offline";
            lblMiamiStatus.ForeColor = Color.DarkRed;
            return false;
        }
    }
    private bool Ping2(string url)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
            request.Timeout = 3000;
            request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
            request.Method = "HEAD";

            using (var response = request.GetResponse())
            {
                lblBayAreaStatus.Text = "Online";
                lblBayAreaStatus.ForeColor = Color.LimeGreen;
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            lblBayAreaStatus.Text = "Offline";
            lblBayAreaStatus.ForeColor = Color.DarkRed;
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I would then need to call each ping with the corresponding site as such,

```
private void tmrPing_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Ping("site");
        Ping2("site2");
        Ping3("exc");
        Ping4("exc");
        Ping5("exc");
        Ping6("exc");
        Ping7("exc");
        Ping8("exc");
        Ping9("exc");
    }
```

Any ideas on how I can condense this?

Comment: If your code works as is, and you're just looking to improve it / make it cleaner, then this question belongs on [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Is there a difference between `Ping1` and `Ping2`? I can't seem to find it

Comment: @TopinFrassi Took me a miute to find it: the label control being updated in the `using` statement is different. Courtesy of Habib's answer.

Comment: I understand one down-vote for placing the question in the wrong section but why four?

Comment: Because people won't stop downvoting because they think you had enough downvotes already, this isn't how things work here. Getting downvotes isn't a **bad** thing, you'll learn from them.

Comment: I don't think down-votes are a bad thing, I'd presume you'd comment as to why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you are only changing `Label` in your code, you can pass that to your method like:

```
private bool Ping(string url, Label label)
{
    try
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Timeout = 3000;
        request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
        request.Method = "HEAD";

        using (var response = request.GetResponse())
        {
            label.Text = "Online";
            label.ForeColor = Color.LimeGreen;
            return true;
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        label.Text = "Offline";
        label.ForeColor = Color.DarkRed;
        return false;
    }
}
```

and then call it like:

```
Ping("site", lblMiamiStatus);
```

You can even have a separate method to send a Head-Only http request to the URL, and receives true/false from that method, based on that result you can assign the corresponding label contents.

Comment: Thank you very much, I tried this earlier but I guess my syntax with wrong ^~^